# isosceles triangle height and base given only angles and area

Tags: trigonometry

If we know only that:

$A=22$

$v_1=30^\circ$ and $v_2=75^\circ$ and $v_3=75^\circ$

How do I get height and base without knowing at least one of the sides?

Edit: v are angles and A is the area.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being very clear about that. Angles are v and A is the area.

Comment: 22+75+75 = 172, hence the shape you are describing is not a triangle

Comment: @hardman, dont you mean 30?

Comment: Changed it to 30. It was a typing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We have that $A$ = $22$

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Then $A = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot AM \cdot MB = AM\cdot MB$

You also have the relationship $AM = AB\cos(75^{\circ})$ and $AC = 2AM$.

Let $AB = a \Rightarrow BC = a$

Let $AM = b$

Then we have the area of the triangle = $22 = \frac{1}{2}$ X base X height= $b\sqrt{a^{2}-b^{2}}$

We also have that $a\cos 75^{\circ} = b$

Subbing this in, we get $a^{2}\cos75^{\circ}\sin75^{\circ}=22$

You can use this to find $a$, then the rest all follows.

Note:

I get the base of the triangle = $2(\sqrt{33}-\sqrt{11})$

the height = $\sqrt{33} + \sqrt{11}$

Comment: It still can't get it to work, sorry.

Comment: Which side lengths do you know? - are you given the length AB or BC?

Comment: I don't know a single one.

Comment: Oh from the question, it seemed like you did, ok well give me a moment I'll adjust my answer

Comment: I think I might have the solution. Half the triangle A=11. 11=0.5bh->h=22b. 11=0.5*22b^2 -> b=1 and h=22. The whole triangle: 2*0.5*1*22=22. Would this be correct?

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't believe that's correct no

Comment: Are you able to follow my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I get the same. a=sqrt(88) --> b=sqrt(88)*cos(75)->b=sqrt(11)(sqrt(3+1). base=2b. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Bisect the $30^\circ $ angle to give two $15-75-90$ triangles.  Use trig to find the relationship between the base and the altitude, then between the base and the area.  Given the area you can compute the base.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As base is then a half of the height, area is given by A=(1/2)(1/2)(h)(h) instead of A=(1/2)(h)(b). Is this correctly understood?

Comment: You have a $75^\circ$ base angle and $\tan 75^\circ=2+\sqrt 3$.  That gives you the ratio between the altitude and half the base.